# Patching django core modules function is not handled using gunicorn

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, monkeypatching

I have a monkeypatch for a django's core function, to override default enconig of the tilde symbol:

```
from django.utils import http
http.original_urlquote = http.urlquote
http.urlquote = lambda url, safe='~/': http.original_urlquote(url, safe)
```

And it works properly using `python manage.py runserver`. I go proper urls generated by django `resolve()` function, e.g. `/user/nf~roj/` instead `/user/nf%7Eroj/`

But once I run my project via gunicorn this patch does not take effect.

What is the possible reasons of such behavior?

Comment: Where is that monkeypatch done?

Comment: It is done right in the `settings.py`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that gunicorn itself imported an `http.urlquote` function before my patch.

The solution was to do this

```
import django.core.urlresolvers
from django.utils import http
http.original_urlquote = http.urlquote
django.core.urlresolvers.urlquote = http.urlquote = lambda url, safe='~/': http.original_urlquote(url, safe)
```

Very useful trick if you're monkeypatching python.